# After updating username how do set that as session

Tags: session

I have an update form and whenever the username gets updated, it messes up the session obviously since thier is a new username.  how can i make it so that the user won't ahve to logout and the session will continue with the new info..

Comment: Have do you manage user sessions? In a database or standard session varibles? Why can't you just reset the session value to the new username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.  Post this after your update or insert script.

$username = $_post["username"];

$_post["username"] = $username;